# with or without dollar sign in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I read the following code inside a react function return statement.

```
 return(){
      <span className="expense">{charge}</span>
      <span className="amount">${amount}</span>
 }
```

My question is with or without $, they just represent a dynamic variable to be rendered right? I saw ${} and {} sometimes interspersed in code and got really confused if they should be interchangeable. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure but you confused that literal template on js and react variable.

Comment: `${}` is a Javascript template literal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals. Plain `{}` is for including Javascript variables in JSX.

Comment: The amount has a $ (dollar) before the number, e.g. $145

Comment: Without. https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Answer (score 10):

To embed expressions into JSX, [you'll use only curly braces](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx). The $ is outside the curly braces, and is therefore interpreted as text.

```
 <div>${145}</div>
 // equals
 <div>$145</div>
```

Inside [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) however, the syntax for embedding expressions is `${...}`:

```
 `Amount: ${145}`
 // equals
 `Amount: 145`
```

Comment: simple and clear!

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure about your example? ${} is ES6 way to interpolate strings. But it should be inside backticks ``.

For example

```
let amount = 10
return(
  <div>
    <p>Amount: {amount}</p>
    <p>Amount: ${amount}</p>
    <p>{`Amount: ${amount}`}</p>
  </div>
)
```

will produce the following output:

**Amount: 10**

**Amount: $10**

**Amount: 10**

I.e. ${} in JSX not inside `` is just a string of '$' + whatever returned from {}. You can find more [here about template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Took me much time to realize that adding one more $ infront of the third would still give `Amount $10`