# how do I add a dollar sign(before braces) as a string in React?

Tags: reactjs

```
function Price(props){
<span>This item is ${props.price}</span>
}
```

I want to use $ as a string, but it doesn't work due to JSX syntax.
how can I fix it?

Comment: `$` will just be rendered as it inside JSX - [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63049251/with-or-without-dollar-sign-in-react)

Comment: What's the error its throwing? Depending on how this is implemented, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This code will display '$' as a string, '$' is not a special character in JSX, you may be thinking JQuery

Answer (score 0):

This should work as is.
Also, You could try another approach using template literal syntax:

```
{`Hello the price is $${price}.`}
```